# SQL test for value not present

Tags: sql

I am trying to modify existing code so that a CASE outcome is selected if 2 circumstances are true. The business rules have changed, so the code below works, it has just been rendered incomplete.
Below is a snippet of the actual code that tests if ANY line items in a particular invoice have an ITMCLSCD of ‘CCC-OUT’.  The rules have changed so that now, ALL line items need to have an ITMSLSCD of ‘CCC-OUT’.
So now I need to test for the presence of ‘CCC-OUT’ and the absence of any other ITMSLSCD  in the set of line items.
Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks

```
    SELECT DISTINCT
    OH.SOPNUMBE HSOPMNBR,
    OH.INVODATE INVODATE,
    OH.ORIGNUMB ORIGNUM,
    OH.CUSTNMBR CUSTOMER,
    CASE    WHEN 'CCC-OUT' IN (SELECT LEFT(IV.ITMCLSCD,7) 
            FROM IV00101
            INNER JOIN SOP10200 OL ON OH.SOPNUMBE = OL.SOPNUMBE
            WHERE OH.SOPTYPE = 3 
            AND OH.PSTGSTUS = 0 
            AND OH.VOIDSTTS = 0 
            AND OH.BACHNUMB <>'DO NOT POST')
THEN 'THIRD PARTY SERVICES'
        ELSE 'COMPANY SERVICES'
    END  TRANSTYPE,
    UD.USRTAB09
FROM SOP10100 OH
INNER JOIN SOP10200 OL ON OH.SOPNUMBE = OL.SOPNUMBE
INNER JOIN IV00101 IV ON OL.ITEMNMBR = IV.ITEMNMBR
INNER JOIN SOP10106 UD ON OH.SOPNUMBE = UD.SOPNUMBE
WHERE OH.SOPTYPE=3
AND OH.PSTGSTUS = 0
AND OH.VOIDSTTS = 0
AND OH.BACHNUMB <>'DO NOT POST'
```

Comment: The code makes no sense. What is `OH`?  What is `IV`?

Comment: How do you expect people to help you if that's all you give????  The query doesn't even run.  Here's a good reference how to ask question.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Added the missing code

Answer (score 0):

So far you want at least one `LEFT(IV.ITMCLSCD,7) = 'CCC-OUT'`. Now you want at least one `LEFT(IV.ITMCLSCD,7) = 'CCC-OUT'` plus there must be no `LEFT(IV.ITMCLSCD,7) <> 'CCC-OUT'`.

In other words, no matter whether you look at the minimum value or the maximum value, both are `'CCC-OUT'`, because all values are `'CCC-OUT'` :-)

One way to write this:

```
WHEN 'CCC-OUT' = 
(
  SELECT 
    CASE WHEN MIN(LEFT(IV.ITMCLSCD,7)) = MAX(LEFT(IV.ITMCLSCD,7))
      THEN MIN(LEFT(IV.ITMCLSCD,7))
      ELSE 'MISMATCH'
    END
  FROM IV00101
  INNER JOIN SOP10200 OL ON OH.SOPNUMBE = OL.SOPNUMBE
  WHERE OH.SOPTYPE = 3 --Invoice
  AND OH.PSTGSTUS = 0 --Unposted
  AND OH.VOIDSTTS = 0 --Not Voided
  AND OH.BACHNUMB <>'DO NOT POST'
)
THEN '3PARTY SERVICES'
```

(You can even remove the `ELSE` branch; that would default to `NULL`, which works just the same.)

Comment: Thanks everyone.  Your answers have helped me get the correct coding.  The next ( and hopefully last) challenge is going to be getting only 1 record for each entry in the header table.  But I will open up another topic for that.